# Do I keep my game progress even if I don't pay for Xbox Live Gold?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

If I have paid for an Xbox Live Gold account for three months and accumulate heaps of progress on a few games, when my subscription ends do I still get to keep the progress? I still have the same hard drive.

This is on Xbox 360.

Comment: If your game saves are stored in the cloud, I do not think you will have access to it.
EDIT: See my answer

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your saved data is separate from the game's code/data.  You would still have it unless you manually deleted it yourself.

Comment: Is this still true for the cloud game saves? I thought that was a feature of having xbox gold, or am I incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to cloud saves, you can still access them but you will not be able to create new saves on the cloud.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/games/game-saves-in-the-cloud-faq#95d1756ae357488399bdb55c646729be